# How do I get the sorting key which I added at runtime to be recognized in the listing processor

Tags: shopware6

When the listing is extended with a runtime sorting like described [here](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/add-custom-sorting-product-listing#create-individual-sorting-at-runtime)
the sorting is loaded. But when the set key is actually called from the query, a `ProductException` is thrown, because the key is unknown.

I added the key in an earlier event, but this does not seem like best practice.

Answer (score 0):

See this [deprecation notice](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/2ba1b221b79313126522d44cd0c1050f623ec875/UPGRADE-6.5.md#deprecation-of-productlistingfeaturessubscriber).

You should add a custom `AbstractListingProcessor`.

```xml
<service id="SwagBasicExample\Processor\MyListingProcessor">
    <tag name="shopware.listing.processor"/>
</service>
```

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace SwagBasicExample\Processor;

use Shopware\Core\Content\Product\SalesChannel\Listing\Processor\AbstractListingProcessor;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Product\SalesChannel\Sorting\ProductSortingCollection;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Product\SalesChannel\Sorting\ProductSortingEntity;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Criteria;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Plugin\Exception\DecorationPatternException;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Uuid\Uuid;
use Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\SalesChannelContext;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class MyListingProcessor extends AbstractListingProcessor
{
    public function getDecorated(): AbstractListingProcessor
    {
        throw new DecorationPatternException(self::class);
    }

    public function prepare(Request $request, Criteria $criteria, SalesChannelContext $context): void
    {
        /** @var ProductSortingCollection $sortings */
        $sortings = $criteria->getExtension('sortings') ?? new ProductSortingCollection();

        $myCustomSorting = new ProductSortingEntity();
        $myCustomSorting->setId(Uuid::randomHex());
        $myCustomSorting->setActive(true);
        $myCustomSorting->setTranslated(['label' => 'My Custom Sorting at runtime']);
        $myCustomSorting->setKey('my-custom-runtime-sort');
        $myCustomSorting->setPriority(5);
        $myCustomSorting->setFields([
            [
                'field' => 'product.name',
                'order' => 'desc',
                'priority' => 1,
                'naturalSorting' => 0,
            ],
        ]);

        $sortings->add($myCustomSorting);

        $criteria->addExtension('sortings', $sortings);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @dneustadt I tried this solution without doing the database migration (using the database migration the error is gone but it doesn't make sense to use both to get the AbstractListingProcessor to work) and I am still getting the error of custom-sorting key not Found error.